# What does XMLHttpRequest.XMLHttpRequest mean exactly?

Tags: javascript, ajax

MDN's writing style confuses me.
Here [MDN's page on XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) says:

> ```
> XMLHttpRequest is an API ... 
>
> Constructor 
> XMLHttpRequest.XMLHttpRequest
>
> Properties
> XMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange
> XMLHttpRequest.readyState
> XMLHttpRequest.responseType
> ```

But there is no such thing as `XMLHttpRequest.XMLHttpRequest` or `XMLHttpRequest.readyState`. If you type these in browser console, it will return `undefined.`

XMLHttpRequest is a constructor function, and properties such as `readyState` belongs to the object generated by the constructor function not the function itself. So writing `XMLHttpRequest.readyState` is misleading.

If you compare these with [`Array.prototype.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) you will see what I mean. If you type `Array.prototype.push` in browser console, it will return a function as expected.

Comment: MDN is a community wiki. Screwy stuff gets in. If you look at the [history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest$history?page=1) for that page, someone called [MashKao](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/profiles/MashKao) made a bunch of changes to that page, many taking place on the same day. So who knows what that person was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

It was a simple mistake in the document. [I fixed it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest$compare?locale=en-US&to=1064658&from=1064498).